# AS3 Flixel Setting control keys as variables

Tags: actionscript-3, input, keyboard, flixel

I would like to store keyboard input as a variable in the class (not the function), that way they're not hardcoded.

if(FlxG.keys.(myKeyVar))

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was overlooking this.

FlxG.keys.pressed(myKeyVar);

ugh